# wordpress Auto-correction echo "<img src='img.png' />"

Tags: wordpress

I placed a code in Footer.php:

```
echo "<img src='img.png' " />";
```

output was:

```
&lt;img src='img.png' " /&gt;
```

WordPress automatically converts
< to==> &_l_t; > to==> &_g_t;

**What to do?**

Answer (score 0):

`echo "<img src='img.png' " />";`
Is wrong. Try:

```
echo "<img src='img.png' />";
```

Comment: no difference WordPress somehow automatically converts < to==> &_l_t; > to==> &_g_t;

Comment: But thats not true, so it has to be something else. In what context is your code?

Comment: at the bottom **Footer.php**

Comment: And thats the only content of footer.php?

Comment: Footer.php http://pastebin.com/8Msyc5Ze **echo "<_img src=\"".$Links[$iLinksCountArray]."\" class=\"PreLoad_Page_In_Background\" />\n";**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43829/discussion-between-veelen-and-user1942505)